# Drawing contour plots with parametric plots or polar coordinates

Tags: pgfplots, gnuplot

I have two 3D plots, one in polar coordinates, the other parametric. I'd like to have on the same plot also the contours. These are the current plots:

[image: Elliptic paraboloid]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[view={130}{30}]
      \addplot3 [surf,z buffer=sort,samples=30,domain=0:360,y domain=0:5, data cs=polar] (x,y,y^2);
      \addplot3 [contour gnuplot={contour dir=y,draw color=red,labels=false},y filter/.expression={5},] {x^2};
      \addplot3 [contour gnuplot={contour dir=x,draw color=blue,labels=false},x filter/.expression={5},] {y^2};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Elliptic hyperboloid]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[view={130}{30}]
    \addplot3[surf,domain=-1:1,y domain=0:360,z buffer=sort] ({cosh(x)*cos(y)}, {cosh(x)*sin(y)}, {sinh(x)});
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

My question now is: how could I automatically plot the  contours of both plots since they are defined via polar coordinates or parameters? The `x` and `y` contours of the paraboloid are just hardcoded.

I am looking for (if there is one) a way to create automatically the contours, without caring what coordinates it is using. Kind of like the example at page 156 [here](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf)

I have also managed to get something like this
[image: pt2]
adding the following line:

```
\addplot3 [contour gnuplot={contour dir=z,draw color=black,labels=false},z filter/.expression={25},] {y^2+x^2};
```

but the solution does not seem optimal since I have to manually know the section. Is there a way to achieve this?

---

Edit 1: I perhaps should clarify my need. Suppose I have a function `f` that I want to plot. I can use its cartesian formula, some parameterization or use polar coordinates. Either way, the same result should be achieved. In the first case, finding contours with the aid of `contour gnuplot` is quite easy and I just have to input the original function.

If I have `f` in a parametric form or that is using polar coordinates though, I have to already know the contour equations to plot them.
Is there a way to generalize the problem s that for any given `f` written in any form, I am able to plot the contours?

Basically I would like to have the projection of the function `f` on the axis and plot its countour.

Comment: Nothing actually prevents me from using it to be completely fair. I would just like a more automated way. In the example I linked, the contour was not "hardcoded" but the function (the hyperbolic paraboloid) was just passed as parameter. I would like to know if I have to manually know the contours (that in some cases might be very complicated) or I can let pgf do the work for me even for the more complex functions.

Comment: Not really. Perhaps the whole question is meaningless and I am just missing a point. Let's take the second function (`x^2+y^2-z^2=1`) I would like to have the same kind of contours on the box, as the example on the manual. The thing is that the function is in the parametric form. I was asking myself if there was a way to create the contours without manually plotting them one by one (the example on the manual has multiple contour lines with a single call). Of course I could just plot them by hand but perhaps with more complex functions, this would be unfeasible.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't express myself clearly the first time. I too wasn't sure which terms to use. I hope I now made my problem clear. If that is not the case, I'll try to explain it even further.

Comment: Correct. And if possible learn a way to generalize the problem and/or apply it to any kind of surface.

Comment: I just removed my answer an remove my comments because I seem to be on the wrong track. Hope someone else will have more luck.